# A question about type traits std::remove_cv

Tags: c++11, type-traits

My reference is to the example provided hereunder:

[std::remove_cv, std::remove_const, std::remove_volatile](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)

In the example,

```
using type4 = std::remove_cv<const volatile int*>::type;
using type5 = std::remove_cv<int* const volatile>::type;

std::cout << std::is_same<type4, int*>::value << ' '
              << std::is_same<type4, const volatile int*>::value << '\n';

    std::cout << std::is_same<type5, int*>::value << '\n';
```

> Output
>
> false true
>
> true

I am assuming that there is a typo in the output as it doesn't match the test in the example, if my understanding of the concept is correct. The output instead should have been

> true false
>
> true

Can someone confirm or correct this?

TIA

Comment: If you look at the example in the link you supplied it mentions exactly this. _"Removing `const`/`volatile` from `const volatile int *` does not modify the type, because the pointer itself is neither `const` nor `volatile`."_

Comment: @TedLyngmo well I am a bit lost here. type4 is the same as const volatile int* in spite of the remove_cv trait applied to it, since it compares false to int* and true to const volatile int*. Isn't a const int* or volatile int* different from int*, so that using a remove_cv trait on either does achieve the same result as doing so on a non-pointer type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `const volatile int *`, `const` and `volatile` refer to `int`, not the pointer. `remove_cv` affects the qualifiers of the type itself, which is a pointer without any qualifiers in your case. So the displayed behavior is correct. If you want `const` and `volatile` to affect the pointer rather than the pointed-to type, the construct you used for `type5` is correct. If you want `remove_cv` to affect the pointed-to type, you'll have to remove the pointer and add it back in manually

Answer (score 0):

In the linked document, just above the example it states:

> Removing const/volatile from const volatile int * does not modify the type, because the pointer itself is neither const nor volatile.

(Perhaps the example could be made clearer on this...)